# Make linearLayout disappear from screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hello I have a `linearLayout` of buttons and dropdowns at the top of my activity. They are used to initialize a connection over serial. One I click connect and a connection is established I would like the buttons/dropdowns to disappear, so that there is more space available for other things, and I'd like an option to bring it back, maybe a button. Is the best way to do this change the code to a fragment or soemthing? I ahve never used those? Here is a screenshot, https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRrL.png I want to remove `connect`, `spinners` and `update settings`  Is there anything simple I could do to change this code to do what I want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topButtons" 
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Connect"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="Connected Adapter:"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Spinner android:id="@+id/deviceSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/currentSettings" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:text="Current Settings: Not Connected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Baud:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/baudSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Data:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/dataSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Parity:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/paritySpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Stop:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/stopSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button android:id="@+id/updateSettings"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Update\nSettings"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enable"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Configure"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command2"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Version"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command3"/> 

   <Button android:id="@+id/Command5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Run"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command4"/> 

    <Button android:id="@+id/Command6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Backspace"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command5"/> 

        <Button android:id="@+id/Command7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Backspace2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Command"/> 


    <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
    android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Command" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emulatorView" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/term_entry_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/entry_send"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/term_entry" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/emulatorView"/>

    </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` is this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on your activity to retrieve the `LinerarLayout` with a `findViewById` and then `setVisibility(INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(GONE)`to hide it.

To show it again you can do the same with `setVisibility(VISIBLE)`.

Comment: @Alice With this method would I have to move my other layouts like my relativelayout outside of this linearlayout? or it would disappear too? At the moment I have a relative layout saying place buttons/terminal under the linearlayout buttons at the top, so if they disappear what happens?

Comment: I don't think you'll need to move your layouts as your relative layout doesn't have any relationship with the disspearing layout. Either way, best method to know is to try it :D Shouldn't take too much time.

Comment: thanks I will accept yours. It works perfectly now. Apart from i would like some transition for it disappearing, it to disappear slowly. it just instantly disappears. That doesn't look nice :)

Comment: Well, I don't currently know how to do that kind of AJAX like trasition :D And also, I'm quite sure it won't be something as simple as changing a pair of properties :D

Comment: Yes haha, it's not high up on my priority list anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method with [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) flag to make view invisible and to "remove" it from screen.

Comment: Copy of comment above: With this method would I have to move my other layouts like my relativelayout outside of this linearlayout? or it would disappear too? At the moment I have a relative layout saying place buttons/terminal under the linearlayout buttons at the top, so if they disappear what happens?

Comment: LinearLayout just wouldn't take any space but it still will be existing. So your RelativeLayout should be ok

Answer (score 1):

please add an attribute to you LinearLayout tag:
android:visibility="gone"

if you want to make it visible, just call setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

`view.setVisibility(int)` is what you need.

However, `view.setVisibility(GONE)` won't work from everywhere: it will only work within the view. If you want to hide it from your activity (the most common case), you'll have to call `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, and `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to show it again.